# Xgboost Amazon Sagemaker predict_proba

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have trained an Xgboost multi-class classification algo for 5 classes using the Sagemaker framework. I then saved the model on S3. Now, when I load it, I only have the option of predict, that will return me the classes and not the probabilities of each class.

```
pred = xgb_uploaded_model.predict(new_data)
```

The uploaded model has no option of predict_proba, that would have came in handy. 
Any ideas on hot to get probabilities from this a model saved like this? 
P.S. I don't want to use Endpoints.

Comment: The classification example for xgboost on AWS Sagemaker examples uses "text/x-libsvm" content-type. So, I tried doing the same with my xgboost model but that just returns the value of predict. Hopefully, this saves someone a day of their life. Unfortunately, it's looking more likely that the solution is to run your own custom container. Which defeats a lot of the value of using sagemaker hosting.

Comment: Also, the undocumented 'text/x-libsvm' content-type is just a string that has index number:value and seperated by a space. For example, to call my xgboost model with 17 features an example body is "0:7.0 1:314.0 2:10.0 3:79.0 4:82.0 5:5.0 6:30.07 7:5.74 8:36.08 9:9.6 10:5.99 11:0.1 12:0.0 13:0.0 14:0 15:1 16:3"

Comment: Please, did you solve this? I am here for the same solution! I used endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

## tldr

Under the table, AWS Sagemaker uses three default functions for input processing, prediction, and output processing. One needs to override these functions in the ***Python script used for model training***.

## Description

From AWS doc:

Sagemaker uses three default functions for model serving. Each step involves invoking a Python function, with information about the request and the return value from the previous function in the chain. Inside the SageMaker Scikit-learn model server, the process looks like this:

```
# Deserialize the Invoke request body into an object we can perform prediction on
input_object = input_fn(request_body, request_content_type)

# Perform prediction on the deserialized object, with the loaded model
prediction = predict_fn(input_object, model)

# Serialize the prediction result into the desired response content type
output = output_fn(prediction, response_content_type)
```

1. `input_fn`: Takes request data and deserializes the data into an object for prediction.
2. `predict_fn`: Takes the deserialized request object and performs inference against the loaded model.
3. `output_fn`: Takes the result of prediction and serializes this according to the response content type.

It is mandatory to implement model_fn

You only need to implement predict_fn if your model uses something other than .predict(), useful in your case

You can see how the default function implementations work here

Ref link - [Sagemaker sklearn model serving](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/sklearn/using_sklearn.html#serve-a-model)

Ref link - [Sagemaker sklearn GitHub example](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-scikit-learn-container/blob/master/src/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py)

Ref link - [Pytorch model serving](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/frameworks/pytorch/get_started_mnist_deploy.ipynb)