# When I get a prediction from sagemaker endpoint, what does the endpoint do?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

In sagemaker, the docs talk about inference scripts requiring to have 4 specific functions. When we get a prediction, the python SDK sends a request to the endpoint.

Then the inference script runs. But I cannot find where in the SDK the inference script is run.

When I navigate through the sdk code the `Predictor.predict()` method calls the sagemaker session to post a request to the endpoint and get a response. That is the final step in the sdk. Sagemaker is obviously doing something when it receives that request.

What is the code that it runs?

Comment: Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76180277/5957834

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endpoint is essentially a Flask web server running in a Docker container

If it's a scikit-learn image, when you invoke the endpoint, it loads your script from S3, then...

It calls `input_fn(request_body: bytearray, content_type) -> np.ndarray` to parse the `request_body` into a numpy array

Then it calls your `model_fn(model_dir: str) -> object` function to load the model from `model_dir` and return the model

Then it calls `predict_fn(input_object: np.ndarray, model: object) -> np.array`, which calls your `model.predict()` function and returns the prediction

Then it calls `output_fn(prediction: np.array, accept: str)` to take the result from `predict_fn` and encode it to the `accept` type

You don't need to implement all of these functions yourself, as there are defaults

You **do** need to implement `model_fn`

You only need to implement `input_fn` if you have non numeric data

You only need to implement `predict_fn` if your model uses something other than `.predict()`

You can see how the default function implementations work [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-scikit-learn-container/blob/master/src/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py)