# Use Hugging Face Instructor with AWS Sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to use AWS SageMaker to get inferences from the [Instructor model](https://huggingface.co/hkunlp/instructor-xl) (i.e., to generate embeddings based on the Instructor model) but am running into various roadblocks upon calling `predict()` on the model class in SageMaker. What might be the issue with the below setup, and what is the appropriate way to structure a custom inference script like the one used below?

Some context:

- For question answering tasks, the Instructor model takes the following inputs: an instruction (e.g., "Represent the Medical title for retrieving") and a query string (e.g., "The title of a medical paper").
- Thus, when generating inferences using Instructor, I want to be able to pass in both an instruction and a query.
- As far as I understand, this means that I cannot use the [nice utility](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/sagemaker/11_deploy_model_from_hf_hub/deploy_transformer_model_from_hf_hub.ipynb) that allows you to deploy models straight from Hugging Face (because there is no room in this approach for customizing instructions + queries).

Currently, using [this guide](https://huggingface.co/docs/sagemaker/inference#user-defined-code-and-modules) from Hugging Face as reference, I've set things up as below.

I download the Instructor repository, create a `code` subdirectory, and create `inference.py` and `requirements.txt` in that subdirectory.

`inference.py` contains:

```py
from InstructorEmbedding import INSTRUCTOR
import torch

def model_fn(model_dir):
    model = INSTRUCTOR('hkunlp/instructor-xl')
    model.max_seq_length = 768
    
    return model


def input_fn(input_data, content_type):
    return input_data


def output_fn(prediction, accept):
    return prediction


def predict_fn(processed_data, model):
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    
    data = processed_data['data']
    embedding_instruction = processed_data['embedding_instruction']
    
    documents = data['documents']
    metadatas = data['metadatas']
    ids = data['ids']
    
    embeddings = model.encode([[embedding_instruction, doc] for d in documents], device=device)

    # return dictonary, which will be json serializable
    return {"embeddings": embeddings.tolist(), 'metadatas': metadatas, 'ids': ids}
```

`requirements.txt` contains:

```
InstructorEmbedding>=1.0.1
transformers==4.20.0
datasets>=2.2.0
jsonlines
numpy
requests>=2.26.0
scikit_learn>=1.0.2
scipy
sentence_transformers>=2.2.0
torch
tqdm
rich
```

I then run the following from the model directory to package the model and custom inference code and upload it to an S3 bucket:

```bash
!tar zcvf model.tar.gz *

!aws s3 cp model.tar.gz $s3_location
```

Finally, to create the model and deploy a realtime inference endpoint I run:

```py
from sagemaker.huggingface.model import HuggingFaceModel

# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    model_data=model_s3_location,      # path to model and script
    role=role,                         # iam role with permissions to create an endpoint
    transformers_version="4.26",       # transformers version used
    pytorch_version="1.13",            # pytorch version used
    py_version='py39',                 # python version used
)

hf_predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type="ml.r5.xlarge")

query = 'Which paper discuss anemia?'

data = {'data': {'documents': [query],
                 'metadatas': ['NONE'],
                 'ids': ['NONE']},
        'embeding_instruction': "Represent the Medical title for retrieving relevant documents:",}

hf_predictor.predict(data)
```

The above throws the following error:

```
An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
  "code": 400,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": ""
}
```

Looking into the logs, it appears that Instruct installs fine:
`Successfully installed InstructorEmbedding-1.0.1 ...`

And then there are these possibly relevant parts from three exceptions. Based on the below, it looks like `inference.py` is being read, but I'm not sure what to make of the other bits.

First exception:

- `2023-06-12T00:55:14,736 [INFO ] W-model-2-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - load INSTRUCTOR_Transformer`
- `2023-06-12T00:55:14,737 [INFO ] W-model-2-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Traceback (most recent call last):`
- `2023-06-12T00:55:14,737 [INFO ] W-model-2-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 461, in load_state_dict`
- `2023-06-12T00:55:14,738 [INFO ] W-model-2-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1079, in load_tensor`
- `2023-06-12T00:55:14,738 [INFO ] W-model-2-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     storage = zip_file.get_storage_from_record(name, numel, torch.UntypedStorage).storage().untyped()`
- `2023-06-12T00:55:14,738 [INFO ] W-model-2-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - OSError: [Errno 14] Bad address`

Second exception:

- `2023-06-12T00:55:14,740 [INFO ] W-model-2-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - MemoryError`

Third exception:

- `2023-06-12T00:55:14,739 [INFO ] W-model-2-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/ml/model/code/inference.py", line 5, in model_fn`
- `2023-06-12T00:55:14,740 [INFO ] W-model-2-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sagemaker_huggingface_inference_toolkit/handler_service.py", line 243, in handle`
- `2023-06-12T00:55:14,741 [INFO ] W-model-2-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     raise PredictionException(str(e), 400)`

Comment: You might need a larger instance than `ml.r5.xlarge`, consider `ml.g5*` instances https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/g5/

Answer (score 4):

After much more digging around, I realized there were several things going quite wrong in the above implementation. In case it helps anyone in the future, a non-exhaustive list follows:

- `input_fn()` receives bytes, so must implement some kind of decoding in order for the input data to be in a workable format. In my very simple case, `json.loads()` would do the trick.
- Relatedly, I believe `output_fn()` needs to implement some kind of encoding in order for the data to be streamed back to the user.
- While I packaged the Instructor model, I never actually used it... Instead, in `model_fn()` I simply initialized `INSTRUCTOR`, which is imported in that same file, meaning the packaged version of the model is left completely unused. However, Instructor is a Python package, not a bare ML model. To actually use the resources packaged in the `.tag.gz` file, I would have to implement the Instructor `encode()` method within `model_fn()`.

Ultimately, Instructor is only marginally better than a model like `E5-large-v2`, but `E5-large-v2` can be implemented in a straightforward fashion, so I'll be switching to using that model in the convenient way described in [this guide](https://huggingface.co/docs/sagemaker/inference#deploy-a-model-from-the-hub) from Hugging Face.

A few related that may also be useful:

- [When I get a prediction from sagemaker endpoint, what does the endpoint do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71340893/when-i-get-a-prediction-from-sagemaker-endpoint-what-does-the-endpoint-do)
- https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/using_pytorch.html#bring-your-own-model
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/adapt-inference-container.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/docker-containers-notebooks.html
- https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.ipynb
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/prebuilt-containers-extend.html