# how does input_fn, predict_fn and output_fn work in aws sagemaker script mode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

i am trying to understand how input_fn, predict_fn and outout_fn work? I am able to understand what they are, but I am not able to understand  how they are called (invoked), can anyone help me understand the same

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71340893/when-i-get-a-prediction-from-sagemaker-endpoint-what-does-the-endpoint-do/ for some info

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76180277/5957834

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your endpoint comes up, `model_fn` is invoked so that your model is loaded. When you invoke the endpoint, `input_fn` is called so that your input payload is parsed, immediately after that, `predict_fn` is called so that a prediction is generated, and then `output_fn` is called to parse the prediction before returning it to the caller.